# Anyone implemented Endeca with .NET? Would you recommend Endeca or FAST?

Tags: search-engine, performance, endeca

Which search engine would you recommend for a Commerce website?

We have millions of products in a catalog and we want it to be as quick as possible.

We would also want to make sure that the marketing driven through the search engine will be fast and effective.

What are your opinions?

Comment: I haven't had the pleasure to work with neither Endeca nor FAST. But, the usual question: Have you tried the free/open source alternatives first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only half the answer to your question. I've used it with Java and not .NET. Fast is said to be the better search engine. I don't know. However for Commerce Endeca is considered to be the best. I've used it with a catalog of 5Mil. products and queries are very very fast.
If you use .NET or Java does not matter in the end solution the Search Engine stays the same. 
And what search engine to be used is not answered easily. it all depends on what you want/can spend. My experiences with Endeca are very positive.

Answer (score 3):

We've been using Endeca for several .NET ecommerce website, surely I think it give us faster full text search with little coding in compare with SQL Server, but Endeca is over complexity, it cost us lots of time to update and configure. Its query capability is quite limited, it lacks of flexibility as we get used to with SQL query.

I'm going to reduce Endeca dependency by utilize Lucene.Net for search part.

Answer (score 2):

I have been involved in several .NET implementations of Endeca and have been happy every time. The biggest advantage of Endeca over FAST is the cost and time of implementation.

My recommendation is to document your requirements and send out an RFP. Make sure you include the following as part of the RFP:

- A demo of the proposed solution (make
  sure they clearly explain within the
  Demo what features are included in
  the cost of the proposal and what
  features cost extra).
- Examples of existing customers that
  have implemented this solution on top
  of the same commerce software you are
  using.
- Software Licensing cost (you will
  need to provide details about the
  number of records you have in your
  commerce catalog as both companies
  price based on this)
- A detailed list of available modules
  / plugins and their respective costs.
- Implementation cost.
- Implementation schedule.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Endeca is the best commercial product in my own honest opinion. We've been using it for our millions of catalogs data.

Or you can try Lucene.NET

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider before buying Endeca is that Oracle licenses the product by physical CPU present in a server.  So if you were considering virtualizing Endeca servers into a VCE or other blade virtualization server, you would have to pay for licenses for all of the CPUs blades in the appliance, even if you were only utilizing one of them for Endeca.  This makes Endeca only suitable for physical server installations, strictly because of Oracle licensing issues.